# Что инициализирует DbSet?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

При работе с EF нужно относледоваться от DbContext и в этот производный класс добавить сущности, например

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Кто проводит начальную инициализацию свойст `DbSet<TEntity>` ?

Компилятор? Базовый класс через рефлексию?

Answer (score 1):

> Базовый класс через рефлексию?

Да. В EF Core, есть несколько классов, который за это отвечают.

`DbSetInitializer` ([исходник](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/70288d25c1d9b6b9c5f08d2888c89a8c3a2630cd/src/EFCore/Internal/DbSetInitializer.cs#L52)): это агрегирующий класс, который используется в конструкторе `DbContext`. Самый интересный для нас участок кода:

```
private readonly IDbSetFinder _setFinder;
private readonly IDbSetSource _setSource;
// ...
public virtual void InitializeSets(DbContext context)
{
    // тут поиск подходящих свойств 
    foreach (var setInfo in _setFinder.FindSets(context.GetType()).Where(p => p.Setter != null)) 
    {
        // тут установка свойства
        setInfo.Setter.SetClrValue(
            context,
            // тут создание DbSet
            ((IDbSetCache)context).GetOrAddSet(_setSource, setInfo.ClrType));
    }
}
```

`DbSetInitializer` использует два дополнительный класса: `DbSetFinder` и `DbSetSource`.

`DbSetFinder` ([исходник](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/70288d25c1d9b6b9c5f08d2888c89a8c3a2630cd/src/EFCore/Internal/DbSetFinder.cs#L51)): ищет для нас подходящие свойства через reflection (имеющие тип `DbSet<>`).

`DbSetSource` ([исходник](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/70288d25c1d9b6b9c5f08d2888c89a8c3a2630cd/src/EFCore/Internal/DbSetSource.cs#L50)): он и создает наш `DbSet<T>` объект:

```
private static Func<DbContext, object> CreateSetFactory<TEntity>()
    where TEntity : class
    => c => new InternalDbSet<TEntity>(c);
```

Также в `DbSetInitializer` используется `ClrPropertySetterFactory` ([исходник](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/70288d25c1d9b6b9c5f08d2888c89a8c3a2630cd/src/EFCore/Metadata/Internal/ClrPropertySetterFactory.cs#L38)), который через Expression Trees создает динамический метод для того, чтобы присвоить наш `DbSet<T>` в нужное свойство (что-то очень близкое к `context => context.DbSet = value`).

В итоге получается примерно следующий алгоритм:

1. `DbContext` в конструкторе вызывает инициализацию свойств
2. `DbSetFinder` находит нужные свойства
3. `DbSetSource` создает нужный `DbSet` объект
4. И через лямбду из `ClrPropertySetterFactory` мы сохраняем `DbSet` (полученный на предыдущем шаге) в нужно свойство.